# Can I write regex expression to check a password for some conditions?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, passwords

I am working on a requirement wherein I have to create a strong password. The following condition has to be met:
-> **It should be a combination of Cap Letter, Small Letter, Number and Special character**

Can I write a regex expression for this? If yes how ?

Comment: It is probably beyond your control, but conditions like these do not make strong passwords, but annoy people instead. http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: Please don't invent a series of arbitrary restrictions on passwords. The more restrictions there are, [the less secure the password is](http://xkcd.com/936/).

Comment: @Eric awesome comic clip

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I had written C# code for it and someone suggested me that regex is better and I have no idea of regex so I did not post any code !

Comment: Sorry if my comment was not exactly polite... Anyway it somewhat expected that you do basic web search before asking the question. I.e. http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+regular+expressions+password would give you some decent starting links. Having sample that you tried and did not meet your requirements along with test cases would have made question nicer.

Comment: Problem statement conflicted on create versus validate.

Comment: Why did I get a -1 for my question? I did not deserve a -1 for this ! This is crazy !!

Comment: I agree with GuruC. The guy who wrote the spec should receive many downvotes, the point has been made, but the coder may have no choice, the question is valid and correctly asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, to validate a password of at least 8 characters:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"^               # Start of string
    (?=.*\p{Lu})      # Assert at least one uppercase letter
    (?=.*\p{Ll})      # Assert at least one lowercase letter
    (?=.*\d)          # Assert at least one digit
    (?=.*[^\p{L}\d])  # Assert at least one other character
    .{8,}             # Match at least 8 characters
    $                 # End of string",             
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
```

Comment: I like the way you handled special characters by looking for anything that is not a Letter or Digit.  But for practical use, that would also invite a lot of ASCII characters that could break the program or database, depending on a lot of things.  For passwords, I typically use a character class that allows what I want it to allow, which is generally Keyboard special characters, not just Anything.  e.g.: **`[-`~!@#$%^&*()_+={}|\[\]\:;<>,./?]`**, and I typically don't allow quotes in either UN or PW, just old injection safety habit, may not be necessary with all technologies.

Comment: Woops, I had a tick in the character class which broke it, lol.  **`[-~!@#$%^&*()_+={}|\[\]\:;<>,./?]`**, almost perfectly illustrating my point that allowing "anything" sometimes has undesired results, lawl

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  Regexes are designed for searching/parsing strings, not generating strings.  Is it possible to utilize them in some way, possibly, but the root of your code can't (or at least shouldn't) be reliant on regular expressions.

Regular expressions could be used to validate that a particular password meets some set of requirements (i.e. asking if an already generated password is strong).  Therefore one possible strategy would be to generate random passwords and keep trying until one validates as strong.   That would be a *very* bad idea.  You're much better off writing the generation algorithm such that it always generates a strong password in the first place.

If your question is whether or not regexes can be used to validate user generated passwords then please change the question accordingly, because if that's the case then the answer is "yes".

Comment: The title seems to suggest that he's asking about validation, not generation of passwords.

Comment: @TimPietzcker But then it says create.  Vague and yet here we are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FormsAuthentication, try using the `passwordStrengthRegularExpression` property when configuring your provider.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx#paght000022%5Fsqlmembershipproviderconfig

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(string input,string pattern)` method.

```
if( Regex.IsMatch(pw,"[a-z]") &&
    Regex.IsMatch(pw,"[A-Z]") &&
    Regex.IsMatch(pw,"[0-9]") && 
    Regex.IsMatch(pw,"[!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regex for this, and practically anything.

I believe this will do the trick:

```
^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

I've used this in my project but added a length requirement which I would strongly advise, like this:

```
^.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: This regex is very inefficient. At least remove the `.*` at the start or you'll run into catastrophic backtracking on strings that fail the validation.